# Float bitwise ops

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer, bitwise-operators

I want convert the storage of a floating point number to an integer (the 'number' value is not required to be equal).

If a floating point number (eg 10), is represented in binary (at least on my implementation) as:

```
01000001001000000000000000000000
```

Then it should (also on my implementation) represent the integer value 1092616192.

I am currently doing this through the following:

```
union UNFI {
    float a;
    int b;
};

UNFI n;
n.a = 10;
int bits = n.b; // foo!

for (int i=31; i>=0; --i) {
    bool bit = ((bits >> i) & 1);
    std::cout << bit;
}
```

Which is achieving what I would like, but it is, in its nature, undefined behavior. Therefore I would like to know what the 'correct' way of achieving this outcome is.

From the C99 standard:

```
With one exception, if the value of a member of a union object is used when the most recent store to the object was to a different member,the behavior is implementation-defined.
```

Is that not undefined behavior?

Comment: What is the outcome you are trying to achieve? Simply to output the binary representation of the float?

Comment: Partially, the primary intention is to move the binary from a float to an int data type; or vice versa (depending on complexity of solution).

Comment: What do you mean by "correct way"? do you mean "cross-platform"? Difficult to understand what is your question.

Comment: @Daniel why aren't you simply doing normal float->int conversion? what difference are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I've already outlined this, I am not trying to do a cast. I don't care for the actual data types in question, only for the bits stored in memory.

Comment: In C99 it is obviously not undefined but "implementation-defined". That means you have to read the compiler manual to see what it does. Separately for each compiler! From what I can find, the C++ standard doesn't say anything, meaning undefined - unless there is a compiler extension. The manual, again! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to call `memcpy`.  Most compilers will optimize this to an efficient single-word memory access just like the union, but on platforms with extra alignment requirements, they will do the right thing.  And it won't ever trigger a signalling NaN.

```
float a = 10;

char bits[sizeof a];
memcpy(bits, &a, sizeof a);
```

or

```
int b;
static_assert(sizeof b == sizeof a);
memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof a);
```

Comment: @Ben Voigt Could this cause a NaN signal if the NaN result was in a register and had to be copied into `a` first before it could be `memcpy` d (in other words the very act of reading from the floating point register)?

Comment: `memcpy` is a legacy C library routine. I'm not disagreeing with you, but it seems like there ought to be a more C++ish way to do this...

Comment: @T.E.D: Why? This **is** low level C code, down to the bits! C++ doesn't do that kind of stuff.

Comment: @Mark B: Maybe, but you first need the signalling NaN in an FPU register. Getting it there would cause a signal if enabled. Furthermore, the FP register spill is logically part of the earlier assignment. Although what you say might be possibly with assembly instructions, I think the C++ compiler can't reorder the spill after changing the FPU exception mode, so if there's an enregistered SNaN, FPU signals must be turned off.

Comment: @T.E.D.: C way: `#include <stdlib.h>`  More C++-ish way: `#include <cstdlib>`  Happy now?  (`std::copy` is not a replacement for `memcpy`, it's a replacement for type-safe usage of `memcpy`, which this is not).

Answer (score 0):

What's undefined?
The layout of an IEEE float is very well defined, the only extra complication is the byte ordering on your platform (and how big is an int)

Comment: From the C99 standard: "With one exception, if the value of a member of a union object is used when the most recent store to the object was to a different member, the behavior is implementation-defined". Is that not undefined behavior?

Comment: Or is it simply "implementation-defined", therefore assuming I never expect the int to be == float in terms of numerical value, I should be OK?

Comment: @Daniel: Why are you reading the C99 standard if you are programming in C++?  C++ is not a superset of C99, and the behavior is different in many cases.

Comment: Granted, however I simply came from C last time I worked with a similar problem, hence perhaps you could please point out the correct answer (or at least reference it) so I can go on my merry way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is in fact undefined in C++ as well, but it's undefined behavior that most/all compilers implement in the obvious way.

Comment: @Mark: In C, which doesn't have strict aliasing rules by default (you can enable them with the `restrict` keyword), this is simply implementation-defined behavior.  In C++, punning types other than `char` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is simple type hosing. What you are doing seems like the easiest thing. Another alternative I suppose would be pointer conversion.

```
int const bits = *(reinterpret_cast<int *>(&n))
```

Comment: That IS undefined behavior (illegal type punning).  It wreaks havoc with the optimizer.

Comment: @Ben Voigt- Interesting. I have to do this kind of thing a lot in device drivers (generally converting from arrays of unsigneds to arrays of floats). Would declaring `n` to be `volatile` help the optimizer get things straight?

Comment: I don't believe so actually. In gcc you can use `-fno-strict-aliasing` at the cost of preventing any optimizations based on those assumptions. Also, you can't `static_cast` pointers to unrelated types such as float and int.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` fixes the compile error, but it's still UB.